# Dropping Flask-SQLAlchemy table raises AttributeError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to drop a table on my database, but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute '_run_visitor'
```

How do I drop a Flask-SQLAlchemy model's table?

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class DeleteTable(Resource):
    def get(self):
        CardsDB.__table__.drop(db)

class CardsDB(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Cards'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    viewID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Views.id'))

api.add_resource(DeleteTable,'/user/delete/table')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`drop`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.drop) takes an engine, not a Flask-SQLAlchemy extension object.

```
Card.__table__.drop(db.engine)
```